# Getting the Direct3D device capabilities in C# XAML project

Tags: c#, xaml, direct3d

Is there any way to get the current Direct3D devices capabilities from a Windows Store XAML/C# application?

I am initialising a 3rd party 3D engine in the SwapChainBackGroundPanel, and trying to set some command line arguments based on the graphics device's capabilities.

Any pointers would be welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to write a WinRT Component in C++.  The WinRT component's methods will be automatically callable from C# and JavaScript.  Take a look at the [ControllerSketch sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XInput-and-JavaScript-c72fe535) for an example of how to write a C++ WinRT component.  In your case, you would implement the feature detection code in C++, and return the results via the component's interface.